# Need explanation of arguments to kthread_create()

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am currently reading Linux kernel development By Robert Love. While reading about threads, I came across kthread_create() function which takes several arguments and spawns a kernel thread accordingly.

```
struct task_struct *kthread_create(int (*threadfn)(void *data),
  void *data,
  const char namefmt[],
  ...)
```

As far as I know, the first argument is the pointer to the function, second one is the argument to the threadfn(), namefmt is the name of the process. Can someone please explain what are those variable arguments are at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`namefmt` is a `printf`-style format string, the varargs are the corresponding arguments (if any).

See [the `kthread_create` description](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/basics.html#c.kthread_create) in the kernel documentation.